# How to Use Trigger to Change RadioButton's StackPanel Background When the RadioButton is Checked

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have multiple RadioButton where a single one is composition of an Image and a TextBlock wrapped with StackPanel

```
<RadioButton
    Tag="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Name="rdbOutlook">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="Resources/outlook.png"
            Stretch="Fill"
            Width="50"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Outlook/Hotmail" />
    </StackPanel>
</RadioButton>
```

I want to set the StackPanel background to such a color when the RadioButton is checked.

How could do that by using Window.Resources to avoid code duplication and ease the modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code for all `RadioButton`s containing a `StackPanel`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}, Path=IsChecked}" 
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Thistle" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Could you give little explanation why twice usage of RelativeSource?

Comment: Abdulkarim, didn't you see? I also used `Binding` twice! – Don't ask me, that's `Xaml` syntax. `Xaml` means »learn slow, forget fast, understand not«.